# Border-bottom и два цвета

Tags: css

Нужно сделать, чтобы в меню при наведении на элемент `border-bottom` был двух цветов, как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там внизу див скорее, внутри которого еще 2 по 50% с разным цветом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно решить вот так

```css
.border-shadow {
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.border-shadow:hover:before,
.border-shadow:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
}

.border-shadow:hover:before {
  background-color: #0000cc;
  left: 0;
}
.border-shadow:hover:after {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="border-shadow" href="#">hover text 1</a>
<a class="border-shadow" href="#">hover text 2</a>
<a class="border-shadow" href="#">hover text 3</a>
<a class="border-shadow" href="#">hover text 4</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все проще чем кажется

```css
.border {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, yellow 51%) 1 1;
}

span:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, yellow 51%) 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>

<span>TEXT!</span>
```

Comment: если упрощать то вообще не бордером а фоном делать и в псевдоселектор его

Comment: Я хотел предложить картинку но, потом отказался )